# Docusign REST API will not send base64 document to Java client

Tags: docusignapi

This has me baffled.

I can request the document content as base64 with curl , no problem.

```
curl  https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<id>/envelopes/<id>/documents<id> -H"Authorization : Bearer <token>" -H "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" -o <filename>
```

Return headers are

```
Content-Disposition: file; filename="blah"; documentid="1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

and the file is returned in base64 format.

Using the Apache oltu oauth2 library which underneath uses HttpURLConnection I cannot get the response to be sent in base 64. I have the request headers set to

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Accept : */* 
Authorisation : Bearer <token>
```

But all I ever get back is the binary version of the file which ultimately bombs out because the library saves the stream as a string which screws up the pdf.

I can't trace the return header , but the request header definitely has the above fields set.

Is there anything in the Docusign endpoints which look at the User-Agent or anything else to determine whether to do the base 64 encoding  ? Why else would it only ever return the binary stream ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your Java output is not the same and the best way to confirm this is to capture exact JSON/SOAP request posted by your API calls via Java to DocuSign by following steps explained at this DocuSign support article https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging

Please post these and I am sure it will be we will be able to deduce the library "add" that is changing the actual output.

Answer (score 1):

OK thanks @david  for the advice on logging the requests in docusign. I find that the "Transfer-Content-Encoding" header has mysteriously disappeared on arrival at the Docusign server. Some digging indicates that

a. this header is dodgy anyway for non-email uses and that

b. in the Java HttpUrlConnection class it is "removed" as security measure. You can apparently set some flags to revert to previous behaviour. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6996110

In any case I worked around the problem by implementing a class which reads the response as an InputStream and not worrying about base64.

Hopefully this helps a Java OAuth library user save a day of their lives banging their heads against a wall !